# How to change YAF(yetanotherforum) theme

Tags: asp.net

Please tell me about some tutorials or any easy way to change(customize) the YAF.
Change page layout .
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Login as admin. Go to: **Admin->Settings->Board Settings->Theme**. There you can change your site's theme.
Also, to let every user select his preferred theme, you can log in as admin and go to: **Admin->Host Administration->Host Settings->Permission** and check the **"Allow User Change Theme:"**